# get variable from input through ajax to external php

Tags: javascript, php

I have this in index.php I would like to get my input data (range) as variable into my nova.php. When I am trying to use 
$range = $_GET['range']; in nova.php it shows :
Undefined index: range. I think, I should put something like data:{range: range} into myAjax function. But of course it's not working

```
<input id="range" type="text" name="range" class="enter" value="">
<input type="button" onclick="myAjax()" value="Show nearby" />
```

my ajax

```
function myAjax() {
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'nova.php',
       data:{action:'call_this'},
       success:function(html) {
         alert(html);
       }
  });
}
```

and my nova.php:

```
<?php
if($_POST['action'] == 'call_this') {
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","tech","151987","portnew");
// Check connection 
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$range = $_GET['range']; 
// Perform queries
$query = $con->query("SELECT ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(53.216908) )*
cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(7.453240) ) + 
sin( radians(53.216908) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance,     
port_name FROM ports HAVING distance < '".$range."' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20; ");

while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $port_list[] = $row['port_name'];
}
echo json_encode($port_list);
}
?>
```

So basically this script is looking for nearby locations based on latitude, logitude. It's working when I put `...HAVING distance < 150 ORDER BY...`, but I would like to set my range in input, and not using static range

Comment: if any of the answers were correct mark as correct answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this jsFiddle

and you ajax function should be

```
function myAjax() {
var range = document.getElementById('range').value;
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'nova.php',
       data:{action:'call_this',range:range},
       success:function(html) {
         alert(html);
       }
  });
}
```

at php code change this line

```
$range = $_GET['range'];
```

to

```
 $range = $_POST['range'];
```

also the input of type range should have a value defined. ex value="100". don't leave it blank

Comment: And if I would like use variable values from db, so instead of 53.216908 and 7.453240. i will use $lat and $lng where port_name = $port. I will probably need two queries. first SELECT lat,lng FROM ports WHERE port_name = $port;   while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $lat = $row['lat'];
        $lng = $row['lng'];
    }    And then second one where I will use $lat and $lng instead of 53.216908 and 7.453240. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `post` method so use `$_POST` not `$_GET` like,

```
$range = $_POST['range'];
```

And you need to pass it in `data` like,

```
data:{action:'call_this',range:$('#range').val()},
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using `$_GET` and you should use `$_POST` or you can use  `$_REQUEST` when you don't know how the datas are coming

```
$range = $_REQUEST['range'];
```